# Powerpoint 2016: Text visible but grayed out until click?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I want to create slides where text lines are shown one by one, but I want the slide to be essentially fully visible from the start -- but contents to be greyed out until they are discussed. This is the behavior that is implemented by default e.g. in LaTeX beamer.

The idea is to make it *possible* to read the whole slide at once, but to still *emphasize* the progress through the content.

I know it is possible to to so by manually placing semi-transparent white layers on top of the text and then removing them one by one, or similar workarounds. However, what I have found so far has at least one of these issues:

- **Impractical.** The workaround I described is impractical for editing, wasting time that would better be spent on the contents. Enough so, that I'd rather fall back to just using the "appear" animation.
- **Breaks handouts.** I need to produce a PDF document for future reference out of it. These contain *all* objects on the slide, so the handout would have everything grayed out.

Proper animation features have neither of these issues, but I couldn't find one that matches my "visible but deemphasized" goal.

Is there such a feature in Powerpoint 2016 (which is what I have at work)?

*Remark. LPChip has provided a workaround [in the comments](https://superuser.com/posts/comments/2581051?noredirect=1)
and [as an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1681124/191663).
Still not as good as a proper official solution, but viable.*

Comment: I  have seen a video about powerpoint animations that makes this easy to do. You basically create your first slide with everything grayed out, then make enough copies as you have points. Then on each copy, alter the appearance of the text (eg. change color). Now select all slides and add a transition, and it will look very proffessional.

Comment: @LPChip This solution *heavily* has both issues I mentioned. Exporting a handout becomes a nightmare, and making any *changes* to the slides too. It would be a viable option for an automated presentation running on a screen on a fair, but not for a talk that needs to be created under tight time constraints and likely iterated several times and edited last-minute.

Comment: Maybe you can try having one sheet with all items grayed out, then copy that text and place it on top with all black, and use animation to show each line

Comment: @LPChip That workaround is viable, thanks! At least, updating the grayed-out version is fast with this method. Still a matter of "if I have time left", though that's also true for animating the slides in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Considering what you want and what you don't want, an option is to create a sheet with the text in grayed out state, then copy that text and paste it. Edit the color to black or whatever the active state is, move it over the other text so that it overlaps exactly.

Now use animation to draw it on screen on a line-by-line basis.

You might even be able to select both text objects and alter its text simultaneously.